# Decomposition of representation of GCR $C^*$-algebra in a non-separable case

Tags: representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

There's a theorem about a unique (up to unitary equivalence) decomposition of non-denereate (multiplicity-free in this case) representations of separable GCR $C^*$-algebras (see e.g. [Dixmier, 8.6.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETGcw.png)) into direct integral of irreducible ones.

Is there such decomposition in the non-separable GCR case (as hinted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2666554/509391))? Most of the references I found focus on a separable case. Perhaps there are some weaker generalizations for some special (non-separable) cases?

Comment: And a broader question which I decided non to include in the main question: are irreducible representations are not as useful in a non-separable case? Or can we still use them to tell something about any representation?

Comment: what is a GCR C*-algebra?

Comment: @alepopoulo110 it means that image of any irreducible representation contains compact operators (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537120/in-how-far-are-ccr-and-gcr-c-algebras-interesting?)

Comment: @alepopoulo110 I should also mention that Dixmier calls them postliminal